# What is the best way to trace event propagation in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, events

Suppose an application has a chat module containing messages. There is a jQuery click handler on said chat module that fires a series of focus related events whenever it detects a click.

Now suppose that when certain messages within the chat module are clicked, the event never bubbles up and a click event is never activated on the chat module.

How would I troubleshoot such an issue? I have a theory that somewhere in the application an intermediate element between the message click handler and the chat module click handler which is capturing the event and calling e.stopPropagation on it. There is currently no tools in Chrome to trace event propagation though.

What is the best way to trace event propagation in Chrome?

Comment: you can pause the js and step-trough each line of code that fires in the `sources` tab. also make sure an element isn't occluding the click, just right-click>inspect element and see if it's the same piece as the working ones catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `jQuery.Event.prototype.stopPropagation` with a function containing a `debugger` statement:

```
jQuery.Event.prototype.stopPropagation = function() {
  debugger;
};
```

From there perform the user actions that will fire the `stopPropagation` event; this time however a the `debugger` statement will cause the JavaScript to pause execution and you can observe the stack trace to see where it is being called from.

Answer (score 0):

Put an ever-loving crap-ton of console logs everywhere. Not the most elegant solution, but it allows me to see what information is getting passed and where any and all hiccups are.

```
console.log(var);
```

Answer (score 0):

I may suggest you to open the Chrome console (F12) go to elements, select the element of your interest and with right mouse click set the subtree modification.

[image]